# Select2 multiselected values not being retained after postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery-select2

I am having an issue with select2 values not being displayed when clicked on submit or the page postback occurs.  I am loading data from database using ajax helper.

here is my select2 code:

```
$('#<%=fstName.ClientID%>').select2({
        placeholder: 'Enter Reviewer',
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        multiple: true,
        autoClear:false,  
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'BulkPickers/GetRev',
            dataType: 'json',

            data:
            function (term, page) {
                return {
                    appinstid: appInstId,
                    searchTerm: term,
                    selection: $('#<%=fstName.ClientID%>').val() 
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {

                var myResults = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    myResults.push({
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.text
                    });
                });

                return {
                    results: myResults
                };
            },
            initSelection:
               function (element, callback) {
                   var data = [];
                   $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
                       data.push({ id: this, text: this });
                   });
                   callback(data);
               }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. need to populate a hidden field value on change of the text and then initialize with the hidden input value on select2. Here is the full code:

```
$j('#<%=txtVendor.ClientID%>').select2({

        placeholder: 'type the name ',
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        multiple: true,
        autoClear:false,  
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'BulkPickers/GetVendor',
            dataType: 'json',

            data:
            function (term, page) {
                return {
                    appinstid: appInstId,
                    searchTerm: term,
                    selection: $j('#<%=txtVendor.ClientID%>').val() 
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {

                var myResults = [];
                $j.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    myResults.push({
                        id: item.id,
                        text: item.text
                    });
                });

                return {
                    results: myResults
                };
            }
        }
    }).select2("data",vendobj);

    $j('#<%=txtVendor.ClientID%>').change(function () {
        var selections = (JSON.stringify($j('#<%=txtVendor.ClientID%>').select2('data')));
        $j('#<%=hdnVend.ClientID%>').attr("value", selections);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be caused by you not repopulating the items in your SELECT, during the postback (As you populated them using AJAX, and they are not part of your model.)  Hence you are trying to set the value of the SELECT to the id of an OPTION that does not exist.

I had the issue described and populating the SELECT with the item referenced in my model as having been selected, meant that the value was automatically retained in the SELECT, after a postback. No 'manual' setting of the value required. The OPTION has to be in the SELECT, for it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropGroup" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control s2multi" DataSourceID="GroupDataSource" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Id"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldGroup" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".s2multi").select2(
        {
            multiple: true,
            autoClear: false,
            placeholder: {
                id: 0,
                text: 'انتخاب کنید'
            }
        }
    ).val(null).trigger('change');
});
</script>


protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "g1", "$(document).ready(function () { $('#DropGroup').val([" + HiddenFieldGroup.Value + "]).trigger('change'); });", true);
}
```